# What does QPS mean in Foursquare PlaceAPI?

Tags: foursquare

・What does QPS mean on this page ? ( https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/places-api/getting-started/#choose-your-account-tier )

・How many requests can I make in one second?

I think that I can make a maximum of 2 requests per second to endpoints for the Personal Tier Accounts,
but no error occured when I tried to make more than 2 requests per second to endpoints.

Comment: The page you linked already tells you it's *Queries Per Second (QPS)*. If you have questions about what that means specifically, contact FourSquare Customer Service. That's a question related to their services, not a programming related question for SO.

Comment: thank you. I try to contact FourSquare Customer Service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.